# How to add header with colspan row in excel export - DataTable

Tags: javascript, excel, datatable

I'm currently using dataTable with excel export button. I've added header in excel export using javascript. But, How to add row with merge cells in header of excel data? And how can to add the header in every page of excel file?

Javascript

```
var oTable = $('#dataAksesAd').dataTable({
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        text: 'CETAK',
        title: "Monitoring AD_"+date,
        customize: function (xlsx) {
            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
            var numrows = 5;
            var clR = $('row', sheet);

            //update Row
            clR.each(function () {
                var attr = $(this).attr('r');
                var ind = parseInt(attr);
                ind = ind + numrows;
                $(this).attr("r",ind);
            });

            // Create row before data
            $('row c ', sheet).each(function () {
                var attr = $(this).attr('r');
                var pre = attr.substring(0, 1);
                var ind = parseInt(attr.substring(1, attr.length));
                ind = ind + numrows;
                $(this).attr("r", pre + ind);
            });

            function Addrow(index,data) {
                msg='<row r="'+index+'">'
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    var key=data[i].key;
                    var value=data[i].value;
                    msg += '<c t="inlineStr" r="' + key + index + '">';
                    msg += '<is>';
                    msg +=  '<t>'+value+'</t>';
                    msg+=  '</is>';
                    msg+='</c>';
                }
                msg += '</row>';
                return msg;
            }


            //insert
            var r1 = Addrow(1, [{ key: 'A', value: 'MONITORING LOG AD' }]);
            var r2 = Addrow(3, [{ key: 'A', value: 'Nama User' }, { key: 'C', value: ': '+username }]);
            var r3 = Addrow(4, [{ key: 'A', value: 'Nama Pusat' }, { key: 'C', value: ': Pusat1' }]);

            sheet.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = r1 + r2+ r3+ sheet.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
            $('row c[r*="1"]', sheet).attr( 's', '2' );
            $('row c[r*="3"]', sheet).attr( 's', '2' );
            $('row c[r*="4"]', sheet).attr( 's', '2' );
        }
    }
]
});
```

I hope anyone there that can help me. Thanks in advance.